# Mask image by pattern

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

How to mask/crop a picture using the pattern like the image in `UIImageView`? Can any one help me with refrences?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass two images to the below function. 1) Image to be mask and 2) your mask pattern Image.

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

        CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

        CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
            CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
            CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
            CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
            CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
            CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

        CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
        return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

    }
```

You can refer the full tutorial [here](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html).

If you want to clip image by passing some path then have a look at this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2570861/1070711).

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: How can i change the size while masking?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394491/how-to-compress-resize-image-on-iphone-os-sdk-before-uploading-to-a-server